# UK and Italy sharing immigration data

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, italy

2019, I was rejected Italy study visa base on fake bank statements.

Will this affect my UK student visa this yr.

Will I have to declare the reject with reasons.

Do UK and Italy share immigration data?

Comment: Irrespective of whether the UK and Italy share Immigration data, applying for a UK visa requires you to tell the truth and to disclose **all** visa denials, bans etc. Not doing so will earn you nothing but trouble if discovered https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/947434/Suitability-false-representations-v2.0ext.pdf

Comment: I didn’t receive a ban letter only a rejection letter with the reason stated with an option to appeal.

Comment: A rejection is a denial and you will be asked for it. Our advice will be very clear on this matter, never lie in a visa application.

Answer (score 6):

- Do UK and Italy share immigration data? *Possibly, but maybe unlikely*
- Will I have to declare the reject with reasons? **Yes.** Irrespective of whether the UK and Italy share Immigration data, applying for a UK visa requires you to tell the truth and to disclose all visa denials, bans etc. Not doing so will earn you nothing but trouble if discovered.

https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/947434/Suitability-false-representations-v2.0ext.pdf

- Will this affect my UK student visa this yr? *Possibly/probably*. A visa denial by another country does not mean an automatic refusal, however the odds are high with a history of deception. The only way to find out is to apply, making sure that the rest of your application/paperwork is 100% watertight.